# Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb

Tags: arangodb

My arangodb cluster is struggling to stay up.  A node will periodically go read and show messages like this in the logs:

2023-01-11T21:23:04Z |WARN| Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb
2023-01-11T21:23:14Z |WARN| Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb
2023-01-11T21:23:24Z |WARN| Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb
2023-01-11T21:23:34Z |WARN| Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb
2023-01-11T21:23:44Z |WARN| Updated cluster config does not contain myself. Rejecting component=arangodb

I haven't been able to find any info on what causes this.  Network connectivity seems good (all the nodes can reach each other).

This is a 9 node arango cluster: 3 agents, 9 dbservers and 9 coordinators.  Started via the arangodb launcher.  (version 3.10.1)

I have tried trace and debug logging in the hopes of finding a better idea of what is going on but no luck.